# extra closing bracket in xml

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I am using this example to save some variables to an xml file:

[how do I set the current class to the return types results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639554/how-do-i-set-the-current-class-to-the-return-types-results)

This is my code for the settings file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ssscc.Settings
{
  public class AppSettings
  {
    public string ReceiptLine1 { set; get; }
    public string ReceiptLine2 { set; get; }
    public string ReceiptLine3 { set; get; }
    public string ReceiptLine4 { set; get; }
    public string ReceiptLine5 { set; get; }
    public string ReceiptLine6 { set; get; }
    public bool ReceiptLine1Enabled { set; get; }
    public bool ReceiptLine2Enabled { set; get; }
    public bool ReceiptLine3Enabled { set; get; }
    public bool ReceiptLine4Enabled { set; get; }
    public bool ReceiptLine5Enabled { set; get; }
    public bool ReceiptLine6Enabled { set; get; }

    public string GatewayUserName { set; get; }
    public string GatewayPassword { set; get; }
    public string GatewayId { set; get; }

    private static string GetSettingsFile()
    {
      var exePath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
      var sharedDirectory = Path.Combine(exePath, "shared");
      var settingsDirectory = Path.Combine(sharedDirectory, "settings");
      var settingsFile = Path.Combine(settingsDirectory, "ssscc.xml");

      if (!Directory.Exists(sharedDirectory))
      {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sharedDirectory);
      }

      if (!Directory.Exists(settingsDirectory))
      {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(settingsDirectory);
      }

      return settingsFile;
    }

    internal void SaveSettings()
    {
      var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppSettings));
      using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(GetSettingsFile()))
        serializer.Serialize((Stream)stream, this);
    }

    internal static AppSettings GetInstance()
    {
      try
      {

      if (!File.Exists(GetSettingsFile()))
        return null;

      var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppSettings));
      using (var stream = File.OpenRead(GetSettingsFile()))
      {
        return (AppSettings)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
      }

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

When I save the data the, the initial save goes fine and at the end of the file it shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AppSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ReceiptLine1 />
  <ReceiptLine2 />
  <ReceiptLine3 />
  <ReceiptLine4 />
  <ReceiptLine5 />
  <ReceiptLine6 />
  <ReceiptLine1Enabled>false</ReceiptLine1Enabled>
  <ReceiptLine2Enabled>true</ReceiptLine2Enabled>
  <ReceiptLine3Enabled>false</ReceiptLine3Enabled>
  <ReceiptLine4Enabled>false</ReceiptLine4Enabled>
  <ReceiptLine5Enabled>false</ReceiptLine5Enabled>
  <ReceiptLine6Enabled>false</ReceiptLine6Enabled>
  <GatewayUserName>asdfasdf</GatewayUserName>
  <GatewayPassword>asdf</GatewayPassword>
  <GatewayId>sdf</GatewayId>
</AppSettings>
```

When I update the file and save it again, I end up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AppSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ReceiptLine1 />
  <ReceiptLine2 />
  <ReceiptLine3 />
  <ReceiptLine4 />
  <ReceiptLine5 />
  <ReceiptLine6 />
  <ReceiptLine1Enabled>false</ReceiptLine1Enabled>
  <ReceiptLine2Enabled>true</ReceiptLine2Enabled>
  <ReceiptLine3Enabled>false</ReceiptLine3Enabled>
  <ReceiptLine4Enabled>false</ReceiptLine4Enabled>
  <ReceiptLine5Enabled>false</ReceiptLine5Enabled>
  <ReceiptLine6Enabled>false</ReceiptLine6Enabled>
  <GatewayUserName>asdfasdf</GatewayUserName>
  <GatewayPassword>asdf</GatewayPassword>
  <GatewayId>sdf</GatewayId>
</AppSettings>>
```

Which it see two `>>` at the end.

Anyone see why it's saving two `>>` at the end of my xml file?

And my code errors out with:

Answer (score 12):

It's because you're using [`File.OpenWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx):

> For an existing file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. Instead, it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters. If you overwrite a longer string (such as “This is a test of the OpenWrite method”) with a shorter string (such as “Second run”), the file will contain a mix of the strings (“Second runtest of the OpenWrite method”).

While it's not clear from your example, I suspect the new contents are one byte shorter than the old contents, so you're seeing the closing angle bracket from the original file.

I suspect you should just use [`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.create.aspx) instead.

Comment: +1 that was it! tyvm! I'll make note of it on the other questions for anyone searching. Give you the check when the timer is up.

Comment: you never gave him the check